# Entity Framework Core: How to add a composite object?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

There is the following composite object, for example:

```
public class Parent
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ChildRefId")]
    public Guid ChildId { get; set; }

    public Child Child { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentRefId")]
    public int ParentId { get; set; }

    public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

`Parent` and `Child` has one-to-one relation:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Parent>()
    .HasOne(parent => parent.Child)
    .WithOne(child => child.Parent)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

I try to create new `Parent` with `Child` and save it in the DB:

```
var parent = new Parent { Child = new Child() };
dbContext.Parents.Add(parent);
dbContext.SaveChanges(); //<-- Exception!
```

...and get the following exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Parent_Child_ChildId". The conflict occurred in database "MyDatabase", table "dbo.Child", column 'Id'.
```

If I use the db context to create a child it works fine:

```
var child = dbContext.Childs.Add(new Child());
var parent = new Parent { Child = child };
dbContext.Parents.Add(parent);
dbContext.SaveChanges(); //<-- It works fine
```

**Question #1:** I can easily add new entities to a nested collections without using context for create it. But it not works for one-to-one relation. For example:

```
var parent = new Parent();
parent.Grandparents.Add(new Grandparent();
dbContext.Parents.Add(parent);
dbContext.SaveChanges(); //<-- It works fine and parent with one new grandparent were created!
```

Why?

**Question #2:** Please, describe me what I do wrong and how I can save new parent with a child without context to create a child (like nested collections)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is occurring only for the `beta-8` version of EF. After I was updated EF to the `rc1-final` version error disappeared. It may be explained there is no graph tracking on the `beta-8` version yet.

You can find more detailed information [here](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/4424).

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the fluent syntax declaration (modelBuilder.Entity ...), it's not required in this instance.

You also need to use your context to create objects, and you should be specifying the Id key values. It's common to use Int's for keys- coupled with an automated database insert annotation that generates the keys for you. e.g.

```
public class Child {
[Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int Id { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("ParentRefId")]
public int ParentId { get; set; }

public Parent Parent { get; set; }
}
```

You should also use your context to create model objects something like:

```
using(MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext()) {
  Child child = db.Childs.Create();
  Parent parent = db.Parents.Create();
  child.Parent = parent;
}
db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried this (remove the fluent syntax and add the virtual keyword) but nothing changed. I still have the same exception. And as I know the 'virtual' keyword isn't used in EF7 (EF Core).

Comment: Sorry- didn't realise it was EF7. That said, you may be getting this error because you are not automatically generating the Id for the Parent and Child model objects - you could do this using an annotation:
DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)

Alternatively you can xplicitly generate and especify the Id when you create parent and child objects.

Comment: I've updated my answer- you  should be using your context to create objects, and you should be explicitly setting the key value, or auto generating it.

Comment: Thanks. It works but there is not an easier way? I mean EF dependency tracking. For example, I can easily add new entities to a nested collections without using context for create it. But it not works for one-to-one relation. Why? (Please, see my updated question).

Comment: @hcp not that I'm aware of. Nested collections of primitive types might work, but nested collections of EF complex types would require a similar approach to the above.

Comment: Hm...but it works right now in my solution. I don't know how and why, but it works :) And I would like to get similar behaviour for nested objects like for collections.